# SlickGrid set row back color on event onCellChange

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid, backcolor

I use following code to set background color for the row, based on the value changed but it didn't work, the row color didn't change:

```
        MyGrid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) 
        {
            var data = Grid.getData();

            if(data[args.row].IsDeleted == true)
            {
                 args.row.cssClasses   += 'MyBlueColor'; //Set Css Class
            }
         }

       <style type="text/css">
         .MyBlueColor
         {
             background-color: blue;
         }
        </style>
```

Comment: Check how it renders. There is not a space in your CSS assignment, is it combining the name with another class? Is there a more localized background-color set on the cells, perhaps you need a css rule like `.MyBlueColor .slick-cell { }`?

Answer (score 0):

`args.row` is the row index, not the row itself

[check out what is passed as the event args when `onCellChange` is triggered](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L3161)

To change the cssClass of a row based on the data item, you will need to implement a custom [`getItemMetadata`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L369) function to return custom metadata for that row. Check out how this is implemented in [`slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js#L113)

So as a *hack* just to make sure it works, you could replace the `getItemMetadata` function in `slick.dataview.js` with your own custom function that would look something like:

```
function getItemMetadata(i) {
    var item = rows[i];
    if (item === undefined) {
        return null;
    }
    if (item.IsDeleted) {
        return {
            cssClasses: 'MyBlueColor'
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

This will obviously break the original column definitions, but once you figure out how the `getRowMetadata` function works, you should be able to create your own metadata provider similar to `slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js` and even return custom metadata for each column!